# pulling data from a list of lists if each list meets a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I am trying to get a working method in a class I have constructed. This class accumulates a given student's course history. Each course is a list (name, grade, credits, etc) that's part of the total list of all courses for that student. Here is an example course history:

```
[['English 1', 4, 3, 'Fall', '2009'],
['English 2', 3.7, 3, 'Spring', '2010'],
['English 3', 2.7, 3, 'Fall', '2010'],
['English 4', 3.0, 3, 'Spring', '2011'],
['English 5', 3.7, 3, 'Fall', '2011'],
['English 6', 3.3, 3, 'Spring', '2012'],
['Math 1', 3.3, 3, 'Fall', '2009'],
['Math 2', 2.7, 3, 'Spring', '2010'],
['Science 1', 3.7, 4, 'Fall', '2009'],
['Science 2', 4, 4, 'Spring', '2010']]
```

I can figure out cumulative GPA, but I am finding it hard to determine a semester GPA. Here is my relevant code:

```
class StudentInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, last, first, dob):
        self.last=last
        self.first=first
        self.dob=dob
        self.gradehist=[]
    def __add__(self, course):
        return self.gradehist.append(course)
    def cumulativegpa(self):
        cred = [item[2] for item in self.gradehist]
        grad = [item[1] for item in self.gradehist]
        gc = [grad[i]*cred[i] for i in range(len(grad))]
        hrs = sum(cred)
        gpasum = sum(gc)
        cumgpa = gpasum/hrs
        return cumgpa
    def semgpa(self, x, y):
        semcred=[]
        semgrad=[]
        for i in self.gradehist:
            if self.gradehist[3] == x and self.gradehist[4] == y:
                semcred.append([item[2] for item in self.gradehist])
        for i in self.gradehist:
            if self.gradehist[3] == x and self.gradehist[4] == y:
                semgrad.append([item[1] for item in self.gradehist])
        return semcred, semgrad`

s1=StudentInfo('Bob','Dole', '1-1-1911')
s1 + ['English 1', 4, 3, 'Fall', '2009']
s1 + ['English 2', 3.7, 3, 'Spring', '2010']
etc
```

When I type s1.cumulativegpa() it returns the correct total gpa, but s1.semgpa('Fall','2009') returns "[],[]"
Where am I going wrong?

edit: updated `def semgpa(self, x, y):` to include

`for course in self.gradehist:
     if course[3] == x and course[4] == y:
        semcred.append([item[2] for item in course])`

Comment: You're iterating over `gradehist`, but you're then accessing the fourth value in `gradehist`, `self.gradehist[3]`, not the fourth value of the inner list `i[3]`.  You should also make an effort to name things a little more descriptively, it helps catch problems like this early.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely a mistake. I have switched to 
`if i[3] == x and i[4] == y` 
but still end up with empty lists.

Comment: Did you change all the places you were incorrectly using `self.gradehist` instead of `i`?  Could you add the updated lines in an edit to your post?

Comment: Also, when you fix the above issue, you don't want to `.append([item[2] for item in self.gradehist])` is definitely not what you want...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just wrote it that way because that is what worked well in the cumulativegpa method that I included... I am mostly struggling to get this conditional clause to work!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have added the edits to the end of my post, it give the same results meaning I think there is an issue with my conditional clause. Do I need parenthesis in the argument or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can try it like this:

```
def semgpa(self, x, y):
    semcred=[]
    semgrad=[]
    for row in self.gradehist:
        if row[3] == x and row[4] == y:
            semcred.append(row[2])
            semgrad.append(row[1])
    return semcred, semgrad
```

First, you iterate over all rows. Then you only take the rows which belong to the selected semester. Then you can append the values from these rows to your new lists.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is getting me closer... This still returns two empty lists, but if I remove the `if row[3] == x and row[4] == y:` clause, it returns the credits and grades from all courses...
could this mean that there is just a problem with how I am calling for x and y to be matched? It seems as if it thinks there are no matches.

Comment: @ShaunYoung this method works fine. It returns `([3, 3, 4], [4, 3.3, 3.7])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please forgive my ignorance, I had typed in Spring 2009 which did not exist in my records. This works, case closed.

Thanks!